# Assembly for loop repeating 2 times when it's only suppose to do it once

Tags: avr, assembly

*I'm programming an Arduino Nano so I belive that this question should be qualified for this SE.*

I am trying to dim up an LED using a for loop in AVR assembly.

My problem is that the cycle is repeated twice before ending, while it is suppose to end after the first cycle.

A cycle is when the `red_loop` is repeated 256 times (to dim the led up). At that point, the value should overflow causing the variable to go back to 0. The code should stop there, but mysteriously, it does another cycle and then it stops.

Does anyone know why?

Here is my code :

```
.org 0x000

ldi r16, 0b111
out ddrb, r16

ldi r16, 0xff
out portb, r16

ldi r16, 0

; ff00 pin
; ff01 value
; ff02 led

ldi r16, 0b000
sts $ff00, r16

ldi r16, 0
sts $ff01, r16

red:
    ldi r16, 0b001
    sts $ff00, r16

red_loop:
    rcall pwm

    lds r16, $ff01
    inc r16
    sts $ff01, r16
    cpi r16, 0
    brne red_loop

end:
    rjmp end

pwm:
    ldi r24, 190

pwm_pre_loop:
    ldi r17, 0

pwm_loop:
    lds r16, $ff01
    cp r17, r16
    brge off

    cp r17, r16
    brlo on

pwm_loop_check:
    inc r17
    cpi r17, 0
    brne pwm_loop

    inc r24

    cpi r24, 0
    brne pwm_pre_loop

    ret

on:
    lds r16, $ff00

    sbrc r16, 0
    cbi portb, 0

    sbrc r16, 1
    cbi portb, 1

    sbrc r16, 2
    cbi portb, 2

    rjmp pwm_loop_check

off:
    lds r16, $ff00

    sbrc r16, 0
    sbi portb, 0

    sbrc r16, 1
    sbi portb, 1

    sbrc r16, 2
    sbi portb, 2

    rjmp pwm_loop_check
```

Comment: you did not say what `cycle` means, so i am assuming that it means `red_loop` ..... are you sure that the red_loop repeats only two times?.... i am not very familiar with avr assembly instructions, but it looks like the red_loop repeats a lot more than two times

Comment: AVR asembly is not Arduino

Comment: What kind of Arduino is that? Unless you have something like 64K of SRAM, `$ff00` is going to be out of range.

Comment: I suggest re-writing this code in C and taking a look at the assembly output of the compiler as a reference. Also, it might be a good idea to feed this into a simulator. E.g. http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/avr_sim/index_en.html

Comment: @jsotola a cycle is when the `red_loop` is repeated 256 times. After that, the value will overflow which will cause the value to be 0. At that point. It should stop

Comment: @Juraj I am programming an Arduino Nano, so this question should be qualified for this site.

Comment: @EdgarBonet. surprisingly, I can write to `$ff00` with no problem. Now that I think of it, it's a little weird that it's even possible...

Comment: The address will simply be "wrapping around" and higher bits being discarded.

Comment: SRAM starts at 0x100 - you should be using that as the base for your memory accesses.

Comment: To make things easier on yourself you should define your variables in a `.DSEG` so you don't have to worry about the addresses. (and don't forget to ensure your code is in a `.CSEG`...)

Comment: are you sure that red_loop runs twice? .... how are you determining that?

Comment: @jsotola red_loop actually runs 512 times (2 times 256). I only want it to run 256 times. I know it because I have a led that is connected to it and it is suppose to light up gradually once only. But instead, it lights up gradually once, then it goes to off and does it again. Then it stops.

Comment: things may not be as you think ..... maybe the LED cycles in 128 steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the register `r17`, which you use as a PWM timing
ramp, overflows twice every time you enter `pwm_pre_loop`:

- when you increments it past 127, it overflows to −128
- when you increment it past 255, it overflows to 0.

When using a counter the way you are using `r17` here, you usually have
it overflow only once per cycle: either you consider it holds a signed
number which overflows from 127 to −128, or you consider it holds an
unsigned number which overflows from 255 to 0. I guess the latter is
more common. Your code is confused about that register's signedness:

- The instruction `brge` (named “Branch if Greater or Equal (Signed)” in
  the instruction set datasheet) tests the `S` (sign flag) bit of the
  status register, which is useful for *signed* comparisons.
- The instruction `brlo` (“Branch if Lower (Unsigned)”) tests the carry
  flag, which is used for *unsigned* comparisons.

You should decide once on the signedness of the counter, and then use it
consistently. Since here unsigned makes more sense, you can just replace
`brge` by `brsh` (“Branch if Same or Higher (Unsigned)”).

Or better yet, remove the second test, which is redundant:

```lisp
pwm_loop:
    lds r16, value
    cp r17, r16
    brsh off  ; if (r17 >= r16) goto off;
    rjmp on   ; else goto on;
```

Note by the way that you can name your RAM variables. And you can use
some of the other available registers instead of the RAM.